# how can i add price to my shop cart like toggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a code that i need help with 
i want to have button A and B like an option for my cart and by clicking 
on them its price should be add to my total price but it should be like toggle (car with color A or color B) if i click on B only B's price should be added on total price.
here is my code

```
<div id="banner-message">
 <button>A</button>
 <button>B</button>
</div>


$(".btn").click(()=>{
let extraprice = this.attr("data-price");

let total = $("#total-price").text();

total + extraprice;
})
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/benjamin_karami/1hd0xvjr/44/ here is some of my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have few issues in your code:

1. First declare the total as global variable (outside of the click event handler function).
2. Arrow function (`=>`) does not have its own `this`, use normal function syntax.
3. The text amount is of type string, convert the amount to number before adding them
4. Finally set the *total-price* using `text()`

```js
let total = Number($("#total-price").text());
$(".btn").click(function(){
  let extraprice = Number($(this).data("price"));
  $('#total-price').text(total + extraprice);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
 <button class="btn" data-price="210">A</button>
  <button class="btn" data-price="200">B</button>
  <br>
  <h1>
    Your total price is <span id="total-price">1000</span> $
  </h1>
</div>
```